# when does unmanaged c++ dll unload from memory when called from C# code using pinvoke

Tags: c#, c++

I have Sample.dll in C++ like this,

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int func()
{
    return 100;
}
```

and in from C# i call this

```
[DllImport("SampleCPP.dll")]
public static extern int func();
```

I want to know when does Sample.dll will unload from memory when this C# application calls function       func();
?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The unmanaged DLL will be loaded into the process the first time a function in it is called (either from C# or from some other unmanaged code) and will not be unloaded until the AppDomain that loaded it is destroyed.  In a typical program you only have one AppDomain, so it would be unloaded when the process terminates.

Comment: Not to split hairs, but according to this [MSDN blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robgruen/archive/2004/11/12/256199.aspx), it's when the AppDomain is unloaded. That will *often* coincide with a process exiting, but it could be different.

Comment: Fair point, though with most programs there will be only one.  I will update the answer to point this out.